# How to install ubuntu 14.04 alongwith linux mint 14 (dual booting)

Tags: system-installation, mint

I have Linux mint 14 in my computer.How do I install Ubuntu 14.04 without removing Linux mint and its data? I just need both OS for study purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Use Gparted. Mint should have it pre-installed. Use it to downsize your Mint partition and to create an `ext4` partition on the new free space. Boot the Ubuntu installer, select `Something Else` when asked where to install Ubuntu and select the partition you made with Gparted.